# Converting Chi Square Adjusted Residuals to p values

Tags: chi-squared-test, p-value, residuals, post-hoc

I am running a chi squared analysis in SPSS on a 5 x 2 contingency table. The overall chi square p value was < 0.0005, so I ran post hoc tests (adjusted standardized residuals on the individual rows) to see if there were significant differences in each row between the 2 columns.

My question is, how can I convert these adjusted residuals to p values? As I understand it, the adjusted residuals essentially represent z scores on the standard normal distribution. So, is it valid to just convert the z score to a p value (2 tails) using a calculator?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please add to your question why you are doing this? The p-values from the tests of each of the 5 rows won't necessarily tell you anything about why the overall chi-square is statistically decisive.

Comment: I am comparing frequencies of different products sold across 2 time periods. I just want to see if the frequencies of each row are independent of time period. Thanks.

Comment: Well, the adjusted residual in a cell is exactly `sqrt(N)*r`, where r would be Pearson correlation between the two dummy variables corresponding to the two categories defining the cell. That means that all the residuals are, in fact, the table of correlations between the two sets of dummies. Correlations with their respective p-values, if you want. P-values not corrected for for the "multiple testing". Do you really need them?

Comment: I think, to submit my paper, it's a requirement that p values be included. If it's true that the adjusted residuals represent z scores, would it make sense that the p value would just be the area to the left (or right) of the residual?

Comment: And I come back to my initial question. The p-values from the rows don't tell you the row effects are different from each other, only the initial $\chi^2$ does this. You would then have to provide another $\chi^2$ for each individual pair of row combinations. Try seeing of the magnitude of the row effects is large enough to draw a rational conclusion without getting into the multiple testing.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. To clarify, let's say the products are A, B, C, D, and E. If I understand this correctly, a significant overall chi square value means that product frequencies are independent of time period, in general. What I would like to do is compare, for example, product C's frequencies across the 2 time periods. After looking at the data, the magnitude of the row effects is not large enough to be certain that the difference in frequencies within any particular row across the 2 time periods is significant or not.

Comment: SPSS says the adjusted residuals for Product C are -2.1 and 2.1 (for the 2 time periods). Is it valid to just do normalcdf(2.1, 1E99) to find the p value for Product C?