# Is it justified to report standardized residuals from a chi-square test of association as a p-value?

Tags: p-value, chi-squared-test, residuals, post-hoc, z-score

I'm having a discussion with someone about conducting post-hoc analysis after a *chi-square* test of association.  In this case, it's a 4 x 2 contingency table where the four categories (rows) are groups and the two categories (columns) are analogous to success/failure. (See example below).

For reporting purposes, would it be permissible to convert the standardized residuals to *p* values?   In this case, would it make sense to apply that *p* to the group (row)?  Note that both cells in a given row have standardized residuals with the same absolute value. (See example below).

Is it permissible to report the standardized residual as a *z* value, and apply that to the row?

1. There is a similar question here:
   [stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129194/converting-chi-square-adjusted-residuals-to-p-values](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129194/converting-chi-square-adjusted-residuals-to-p-values)
2. There is a different post-hoc approach presented here.  Is this a better approach for this situation? The results, at least in the case of my example, aren't terribly different.
   [stats.stackexchange.com/questions/430307/current-chi-square-test-of-homogeneity-post-hoc-analyses-in-r](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/430307/current-chi-square-test-of-homogeneity-post-hoc-analyses-in-r)

If you would, please don't suggest different analytic approaches or post-hoc approaches other than using standardized residuals or the approach in 2. or something similar.  I'm trying to understand what can be reported when examining standardized residuals.

Example in R:

```
Matrix = as.matrix(read.table(header=TRUE, row.names=1, text="
Group  Success  Failure
A      21        5
B       6       11
C       7       8
D      27       5
"))

Matrix

Xsq = chisq.test(Matrix)

Xsq$stdres

#     Success   Failure
# A  1.680948 -1.680948
# B -3.182203  3.182203
# C -1.916576  1.916576
# D  2.502628 -2.502628

pnorm(-1.680948)*2

# 0.09277302
```

Comment: How do you hope to interpret these "p values"?  Why not just report the standardized residuals, which are (far) more useful for understanding the results?

Comment: Thanks, @whuber . I guess the idea is to make conclusions explicitly about the groups (rows), and not about individual cells.  And, of course, because people like *p* values.

Comment: See [Tukey's HSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tukey%27s_range_test) for an approach you might find better for that purpose.